# How to setting default Default SSLContext for simple https downloads in powershell?

Tags: powershell, ssl, webclient

This issue from conscript http://www.foundweekends.org/conscript/setup.html
when I try to install the conscript on my windows 10 via running the offical script(setup.ps1[script source code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foundweekends/conscript/master/setup.ps1)) I met fellow issue:

```
 :::: ERRORS
    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://dl.bintray.com/foundweekends/maven-releases/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.pom

    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://dl.bintray.com/foundweekends/maven-releases/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.jar

    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.pom

    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.jar

    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.pom

    Server access Error: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Default SSLContext not available url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/foundweekends/conscript/conscript_2.11/0.5.0/conscript_2.11-0.5.0.jar
```

I think the issue comes from:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
...
$wc.DownloadFile($url, "$CS/$LJ")
```

Here it has wc object, but they do not assemble the SSLContext for the downloading object.

Can you give me example how to give the $wc defalult SSLContext and can make it downloads https links?

Comment: Your `java.security` errors are not coming from PowerShell, it does not run on Java / the JVM, or use Java libraries. The WebClient lines from the script which download `"https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/org/scala-sbt/launcher/1.0.0/launcher-1.0.0.jar"` work fine in PowerShell on my Windows 10 install. I think it's more likely that your Java install is not configured for newer SSL sites, maybe - these sites are configured to [high SSL security settings](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=oss.sonatype.org&s=52.22.249.229&latest)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting this at the top of your script

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = {$true}
```